# Testing browser's default Html5 Input display

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How to test using Javascript or by any other means if a browser supports a specific Input type?

For example, if the input type is email, which is currently supported by both chrome and Firefox, while date and number types, are supported only by chrome and not by firefox. So, Is there a way to check if a specific input type is supported by a browser, so that I can write my own javascript if default validation is not available?

Comment: check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731303/how-to-detect-html-5-compatibility-in-browser

Comment: Check @Prog Mania link, and if you want more information about it, you can read http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html where there's an explanation on how to detect it on INPUT TYPES Chapter (around 3/4 of the page)

Comment: Thanks @ProgMania I had already checked Mordernizr. I Just didnt want to mess up with one more JS library for my app which is already having a gamut of JS libraries for different purposes.

Comment: @ipeiro that link was useful too.. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Has helped me a couple of times too :P

Comment: But just now i tested for numeric type in firefox. It retains the type attribute - number - in this case. But the validation is not performed by the browser.

Comment: It works @ipeiro .. My mistake was that I tried a shortcut by setting type attribute in the markup and checking the set type from firebug. It failed when i tried to set it using JS code. Sharing this for the sake of others who might do the same mistake.