# How to check HTML version?

Tags: php, html

I created a website and one input is for date using `<input type="date" name="rcdate" />`. It is very handy but it only works for Chrome. The output when I process it using PHP is YYYY-MM-DD format.

The problem is when someone uses an outdated browser (Note: Firefox, IE), the UI is not working (Note: displays a textbox) and the user is prompted to input the date him/herself and the format is always inconsistent and MySQL format for the date is YYYY-MM-DD.

Can anyone provide an HTML version checker so that the user will have a message that his/her browser is not compatible with my site? Thanks. Any other suggestions on how to bypass this is welcome as well.

EDIT:
My code for processing date are as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['rcdate'])){ $rcdate= $_POST['rcdate']; }
$strSQL = "Insert INTO nqascorecard (
    `RcDate`
    VALUES (
    '$rcdate'
    )";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Where is your code to process the date and insert into the db? This looks like an HTML 5 input type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731303/how-to-detect-html-5-compatibility-in-browser

Comment: PHP, or server-side processing in general, would be relevant only if you decided to make it accept date formats other than the YYYY-MM-DD format that `input type=date` is supposed to produce. That would be messy, and the more formats you accept, the more often you interpret data wrongly (e.g., 7/4/2013 as April 7 when the user meant July 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to “check HTML version” in general, but you can use *feature checks* with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or directly in your JavaScript code. That is, you can e.g. check whether the browser recognizes the `type=date` attribute (so that it is reflected in the DOM). However, the issue here is really: what should you do if the feature (like `input type=date`) is not supported? If you have a good backup plan, like using a JavaScript widget, why not simply use it *instead of* `input type=date`? Moreover, it is possible that the feature check does not really work: a browser might recognize `type=date` but fail to provide a reasonable UI that implements it.

When support to `input type=date` has become widespread and when (or if) has been properly localized (current HTML5 drafts are messy about this, and implementations tend to localize by *system* locale, not *page* locale), you can use `input type=date` with simple backup: if the browser does not support it (so that it falls back to a simple text input box), insert instructions that tell the user to use the yyyy-mm-dd format. Or, to be on the safer side, put those instructions into the static content and remove them with JavaScript if you can detect that the browser has real support to `input type=date`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be much better to use something like Modernizr to detect if the date type is supported and implement a javascript fall back for a date picker if it doesn't. Not many desktop browsers support the date input method. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: I think it is useful but it may take time before I can implement modernizr to my work. Great idea though. Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't really take any longer to implement than a browser sniffer to tell them to upgrade their browser. It would literally take like 10 lines of javascript. And I see in your other comment that you are implementing for a particular company, if that is the case, can't you find out what browser they use and code to that?

Comment: There are different varieties of browsers used. Most employees use IE and Firefox while most bosses use Chrome, Rockmelt, Opera and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 "date" input type is not currently supported by Firefox and Internet Explorer according to w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

However, there are JavaScript-based calendars like this one form jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ that are built to be cross-browser compatible, so I would recommend using something like that so you don't have to do browser-sniffing.

Comment: Great answer... However the company that will be using this may have disabled the javascript function for their IE/Firefox browser. Limited internet connectivity and authorization for the user may pose a problem when I implement this on their intaranet.

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools.com, there's a reason (many reasons) for interventions like http://www.w3fools.com/! Better refer to something like http://caniuse.com/#search=date or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility