# How to detect browser support HTML 5 or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, modernizr, sniffer

Can any one help meto detect browser supports html5 and css3 or not ?
I have tried this code :

```
if(Modernizr.canvas){
        alert('Html 5 support');
    }
    else{
        alert('HTML 5 not supported');  
    }
```

But this always show "Html 5 supoort" while IE6 doesn't support HTML 5.

THanks,
M

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect HTML 5 compatibility in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731303/how-to-detect-html-5-compatibility-in-browser)

Comment: You can't detect HTML5 support; you detect support for _features_ of HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your problem without more detail.

Use below code to detect again:

```
function supportCanvas() {
    /* 
       maybe use code below for detail:
       var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
       alert(typeof cvs.getContext); // if support, output "function"
    */
    return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check html5 support by checking localstorage feature

```
 if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
alert('localStorage is available!');
 // run localStorage code here...
 }
 else {
 // no native support for local storage
 alert('This Browser Doesn\'t Support Local Storage.');
 }
```